# Bad request for field slot 0,1 on rawQuery() Cursor

Tags: android, sql, cursor, request

I am pretty new to android, and I have the following problem.
This is my code where I'm trying to get data from the database into my list.

```
private List<Model> getModel(int a) {

    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.d("Model Int: ", "Model int: " +  a);
    sql = "SELECT * FROM shows";
    resultCursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String [] {});
    resultCursor.moveToFirst();

    List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
        list.add(get(Html.fromHtml(resultCursor.getString(a)).toString()));

    for (resultCursor.moveToFirst(); resultCursor.moveToNext(); resultCursor
            .isAfterLast()) {

            list.add(get(Html.fromHtml(resultCursor.getString(a))
                    .toString()));

    }

    startManagingCursor(resultCursor);
    resultCursor.close();
    db.close();
    dbHelper.close();

    return list;
}
```

that works fine, but when i do not want to get all the columns with * but with

`sql = "SELECT title subtitle FROM shows";`

instead. I get errors like this

> ERROR/CursorWindow(371): Bad request for field slot 0,1. numRows =
>   162, numColumns = 1

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT title subtitle FROM shows
```

Really means

```
SELECT title AS subtitle FROM shows
```

In english: select only one column: `title`, but rename that column to "subtitle" in the resultset.
This is called assigning an `alias` to a column.
See: http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-aliases.htm

**Solution**
Do:

```
SELECT title, subtitle FROM shows
```

Now you are selecting two columns.

**Disclaimer**
*I do not vouch for the quality of the info in that link, there are a lot of poor quality `tutorials` on the net.  I just looked at the "alias" section and **that** section looks useful.*

Comment: @Amiroo, Those are the mistakes that take the longest to see. Esp at the end of the day :-).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't perfectly understand your question but I think u need specific field then

```
select title, subtitle from shows
```

define the fields seperated by commas